# Change the size of text if charcters > at 15

Tags: actionscript-3, font-size

I've got a list that displays items taken from my database.

```
 createListItem( j, products[i]); // j control the position and i points to particular element of array..
 j++;
```

Items are movies titles. Some are short, and some are very long. 
At the moment I have defined the size of the titles at 26 :

```
function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {

    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 26
    myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
    myFormat.color = 0xA2947C;
    myFormat.font = "Ebrima";
    myFormat.bold = true;
    listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    listItem.text = String(item.title).substring(0,12);
    list.addChild(listItem);

}
```

I'd like to change the size of the titles that are longer than 15 characters.

I've tried :

```
if (item.title.length > 15){
    trace("the item"+item.title+"is > at 10")
    myFormat.size = 10
}
myFormat.size = 26
        myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        myFormat.color = 0xA2947C;
        myFormat.font = "Ebrima";
        myFormat.bold = true;
        listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        listItem.text = String(item.title).substring(0,12);
        list.addChild(listItem);
```

But, as you can imagine, it's the `myFormat.size = 26` that is applied.

How can I change the size specifically to the `item.title.length > 15` ?

Thx

Comment: You might change the size to 10 but since right after that you change it back to 26 it will always be 26. Simply put the "myFormat.size = 26" inside a "else"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myFormat.size = item.title.length > 15 ? 10 : 26
```

Comment: Thx for the quick answer but it seems that, with this code, it's the opposite. Every titles that have more than 15 characters are in size 26 and the others at 10.

Comment: it's typo, he used "item.length" instead of "item.title.length"